# TCP Sockets Listener - Request getting changed from POST to GET?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, html-post

I have created TCP proxy which listens on port 80 (port 80 is not being used by any other service) for incoming connections. The proxy is able to receive the POST Requests When I use "Localhost" or "127.0.0.1" as the IpAddress
for listener socket.

```
Socket listner = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
IPEndPoint localEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 80);
listner.Bind(localEndpoint);
listner.Listen();
```

However when I replace 'localhost' with the IP (191.151.43.22) of my machine.The proxy receives the client requests as "GET request"

```
Socket listner = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
IPEndPoint localEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("191.151.43.22"), 80);
listner.Bind(localEndpoint);
listner.Listen();
```

Client request when listening for connections using localhost / 127.0.0.1

```
   POST /?toke=abc455/../Control.html?s=783&i=0&t=134 HTTP/1.1

    Host: localhost:58888
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 0
    Origin: http://localhost:58888
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) C
    hrome/21.0.1180.89 Safari/537.1
    Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
    Accept: */*
    Referer: http://localhost:58888/?toke=abc455/../Stream.html?s=0&d=%22
    localhost%22&p=0&t=1348652703126
    Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
    Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
    Cookie: style=null
```

Client request when listening for connections using  IP (191.151.43.22) of my machine

```
GET /?token=abc344/../Stream.html?s=0&d=%22localhost%22&p=0&t=13486531
37269 HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.53.50
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) C
hrome/21.0.1180.89 Safari/537.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

Why POST is not working with IP address of the system but working when 'localhost' is used in place of IP.

Comment: The request information by itself doesn't reveal much, aside from the fact that you're going to different paths Control.html vs Stream.html.  This sounds like it's a proxy configuration question and in that case likely doesn't belong on SO.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, your HTTP request is getting altered by a proxy server (my guess would be your router).

With that said, the proxy server (assuming that is the culprit) may not be incorrect with what it is doing. I don't see any POST data in your requests**, therefore the change made should have no functional impact on the receiving end.

<sub>** There is GET data (which resides in the URL), but no POST data (which resides after the headers).</sub>